# is it expensive or necessary to relocate the sub panel from my bathroom to another room in my small condo?

Tags: subpanel

My inspector stated it was an area of concern that my sub panel is located in my bathroom and should have it relocated to another room due to possible moisture getting in; Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: What was the reason for the inspection?

Comment: What room sits on the other side of the wall the subpanel is in?

Comment: Current code , electrical panels are not allowed in bathrooms and clothes closets. Code doesn’t require a system that was installed within code to be updated. Is it a good idea sure but I have seen basements that were much wetter than bathrooms. A sub panel would not be as big a deal to move as a main panel. If you are going to rent some jurisdictions require updates like breaker panels not fuses for 1 example.  If no change in occupancy normally you do not need to change, why the inspection?